# MySQL Server - Remote Access - "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts"

Tags: c#, mysql, remote-access, mysql-connector, connector

I've built a C#-application and now I want to connect that application with an MySQL-Server that is running in my local network.

For this purpose I used the MySQL-connector like the following:

```
        string connectionString = "server=192.168.0.11;uid=User1;pwd=PWD1234;database=Caller;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
```

But everytime I want to connect to the database and open the connection, it fails with the error "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.".

I've tried a couple of different things:

1. Granted all privileges on the user

   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'User1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PWD1234' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
2. Changed the MySQL-configuration file

   Now it doesn't contain a line like bind-adress or skip-networking anymore.
3. Restarted the MySQL server

So where is the problem? I am not able to figure it out... 
The server is running on Ubuntu Server, actual version.

Thank you and with best regards,
Nicolas

Comment: Try using port number: `string connectionString = "server=192.168.0.11;port=3306;uid=User1;pwd=PWD1234;database=Caller;";` (https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/). If it still doesn't work then use either connection pooling, ensuring firewall/inbound rule settings or executing `netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=10000 num=50000`.